# Swift Core Data Storing Custom Class return nil

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I want to store Arrays with custom Objects to Core Data. I want to store two arrays with custom Classes. The first would be checkpoints as Array<[Checkpoint]> and the second one would be track as Array . Here's the Data Model: [Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM1yD.png)

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

public class Checkpoint: NSObject, NSCoding {
    public static var supportsSecureCoding = true

    public var longitude:Double?
    public var latitude:Double?
    public var instruction:String?
    public var tts:Bool?
    public var len_track:Int?

    init(longitude: Double, latitude: Double, instruction: String, tts: Bool, len_track: Int) {
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.instruction = instruction
        self.tts = tts
        self.len_track = len_track
    }

    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
        coder.encode(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
        coder.encode(instruction, forKey: "instruction")
        coder.encode(tts, forKey: "tts")
        coder.encode(len_track, forKey: "len_track")
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        guard let longitude = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "longitude") as? Double,
              let latitude = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "latitude") as? Double,
              let instruction = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "instruction") as? String,
              let tts = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "tts") as? Bool,
              let len_track = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "len_track") as? Int else {
            return nil
        }
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.instruction = instruction
        self.tts = tts
        self.len_track = len_track
    }
}

public class Coordinates: NSObject, NSCoding {
    public static var supportsSecureCoding = true

    var latitude: Float?
    var longitude: Float?

    init(longitude: Float, latitude: Float) {
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
    }

    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
        coder.encode(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        guard let longitude = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "longitude") as? Float,
              let latitude = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "latitude") as? Float else {
            return nil
        }
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.latitude = latitude
    }
}
```

Apart from the two Transformable Entities, everything can be stored normally. But when I add checkpoints and track to a route, I get the following error:

```
Thread 1: "*** -decodeObjectForKey: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder: Create a concrete instance!"
```

Comment: But why? Use multiple entities and relationships instead.

Comment: Your classes look like they're `NSCoding`- compliant, but there's nothing about Core Data in your sample code, so it's impossible to tell what might be wrong. Can you show what the code looks like when you add checkpoints?